# How would Sphinx Search index / handle JSON files?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sphinx

I have a mysql database that stores mainly JSON objects. I am thinking of using Sphinx to search through it - but i was wondering how would i index and retrieve these json objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wise to have a field in the database which contains the important text stored in the JSON object. If your JSON objects are books, I would store the title, author and publisher as plain text in a database field `search_text` as you commit the JSON to the database.

Your SQL Query for the indexer might look like this

```
sql_query = SELECT id, search_text FROM json_object;
```

I haven't tested how Sphinx handles raw JSON, although it can strip HTML via the `html_strip = 1` conf setting. If you wanted something REALLY dirty, you could strip punctuation and JavaScript syntax from the json field with a series of nested MySQL string REPLACE() functions at indexing time.

```
sql_query = SELECT id, REPLACE( REPLACE(raw_json, ']', ' '), '[', ' ') as search_text FROM json_object;
```

But you wouldn't want to do that would you?

Comment: Thanks for the great tips! haha, no, i do not really want to do that, but that is a great alternative if everything else fails. hmmm

Answer (score 1):

Even better solution: use [an XML pipe](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#xmlpipe2). Sphinx allows you to specify a script to run to build the pipe. Use that script to select your data, decode your json strings, and spit it out as XML. You can also include your schema within the XML, which would give you the benefit of having a dynamically generated schema.